# Markdown link in github

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

Why the link looks different:

Markdown code:
[image]

Editor Looks:

[image]

Github looks:

[image]

Comment: Which editor? Remove the spaces before and after `]`, anyway.

Comment: The editor i use is macdown 2

Comment: Like Ryan said, you have to remove the whitespace between the bracket and parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks! is new editor, i use joe before.

Comment: https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=%5Btest+%5D+(https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F)